How do I configure Symfony Validator to ignore @OA annotations?
I'm using both OpenAPI OA annotations with Swagger and Symfony Validator annotations, but there seems to be a conflict between the two.
Example snippet:
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;

/**
 * @OA\Schema()
 */
class CustomerPostBody
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public string $id;
}

Error when running with PHP:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank" in property app\Customer::$id was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

How do I configure Symfony Validator to fully ignore all @OA annotations?
I'm on PHP 7.4 (can't be changed right now), so I'm using the 5.x validator package.
I'm not using any yaml files for configuration.
Adding ignore statements works only when I do @OA, not for @OA\Schema.
AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('OpenApi\Annotations');

Full stacktrace:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank" in property app\Customer::$customer_id was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? in app/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:40
Stack trace:
#0 app/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php(804): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException::semanticalError()
#1 app/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php(724): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocParser->Annotation()
#2 app/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/DocParser.php(377): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocParser->Annotations()
#3 app/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationReader.php(179): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocParser->parse()
#4 app/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/PsrCachedReader.php(155): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader->getPropertyAnnotations()
#5 app/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/PsrCachedReader.php(88): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\PsrCachedReader->fetchFromCache()
#6 app/vendor/symfony/validator/Mapping/Loader/AnnotationLoader.php(127): Doctrine\Common\Annotations\PsrCachedReader->getPropertyAnnotations()
#7 app/vendor/symfony/validator/Mapping/Loader/AnnotationLoader.php(60): Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Loader\
AnnotationLoader->getAnnotations()
#8 app/vendor/symfony/validator/Mapping/Factory/LazyLoadingMetadataFactory.php(101): Symfony\Component\Validator\Map
ping\Loader\AnnotationLoader->loadClassMetadata()
#9 app/vendor/symfony/validator/Validator/RecursiveContextualValidator.php(306): Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping
\Factory\LazyLoadingMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor()
#10 app/vendor/symfony/validator/Validator/RecursiveContextualValidator.php(133): Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validateObject()
#11 app/vendor/symfony/validator/Validator/RecursiveValidator.php(93): Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveContextualValidator->validate()
#12 app/testvalidator.php(36): Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator->validate()
#13 {main}
  thrown in app/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php on line 40


that error does not seem related to the OA annotation.

app\Customer::$customer_id but your classname is CustomerPostBody and propertyname is id. Please check typos in namespace and classnames.

The error is unrelated to typos.

Where ist your class Customer in your example. --> "The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank" in property app\Customer::$customer_id was never imported."

The validation works fine as soon as i remove @OA\Schema() from the docblock. Disregard the typos, please.

AnnotationRegistry::registerUniqueLoader('class_exists');

As suggested by stof on the Symfony slack channel.
https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/e8c3bb316e385e93a0c7e8b2aa0681079244c381/src/Analyser.php#L13
